# Retrieve method for a polymorphic, has_one and scoped association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, scope, polymorphic-associations, has-one, helpermethods

Hi this is somewhat it trivial but I can't for the life of me figure out where to make the adjustments.
I have a LoanApplication model and a transfer model like this:

```
class LoanApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :populate_guid
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :loan, -> { where loan: true }, as: :transferable
  has_one :repayment, -> { where repayment: true }, as: :transferable
  validates_uniqueness_of :guid  

  private 

  def populate_guid
    if new_record?
      while !valid? || self.guid.nil?
        self.guid = SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000_000).to_s(36)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transferable, polymorphic: true 
  belongs_to :user
 validates_presence_of :transferable_id,
                    :transferable_type,
                    :user_id,
                    :amount,
                    :password
end
```

How come `LoanApplication.first.loan` gives me the following error message

```
LoanApplication Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "loan_applications".* FROM "loan_applications"  ORDER BY "loan_applications"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant LoanApplication::Loan
```

All insights appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Application is a reserved word. Try to rename LoanApplication?

Comment: Thanks for the input, that's not it: loan_application is different from application :)

Answer (score 0):

It was trivial, I just needed to add `class_name: "Transfer"` for everything to work. -__-'